# TestNg Printing the value of the parameters when the data input provider is a CSV file

Tags: java, csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using below code which reads a CSV file and passes the object to the method under test called as public void launchWCM1(IBLogonDataCSV data) .

```
@DataProvider(name = "regCSVData")
    public static Object[][] getCSVData() throws IOException {
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Projects\\Project\\regdata.csv"));
        List<String[]> dataList = csvReader.readAll();
        String s = "";

        Object[][] data = new Object[dataList.size()][1];
        List<IBLogonDataCSV> regList = new ArrayList<IBLogonDataCSV>();

        for (String[] strArray : dataList) {
            IBLogonDataCSV ibLogonData = new IBLogonDataCSV();
            ibLogonData.setURL((strArray[0].trim()));
            ibLogonData.setApplicationName((strArray[1].trim()));
            ibLogonData.setIBLogonURL(strArray[2].trim());
            ibLogonData.setWindowName(strArray[3].trim());
            ibLogonData.setSnapshotName(strArray[4].trim());
            ibLogonData.setRegister(strArray[5].trim());
            ibLogonData.setRegisterURL(strArray[6].trim());
            ibLogonData.setDemo(strArray[7].trim());
            ibLogonData.setDemoURL(strArray[8].trim());
            ibLogonData.setSecurity(strArray[9].trim());
            ibLogonData.setSecurityURL(strArray[10].trim());
            regList.add(ibLogonData);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {

                data[i][j] = regList.get(i);
                System.out.println("In Array" + regList.get(i).URL
                        + regList.get(i).ApplicationName);
                s = s + regList.get(i).URL;

            }

        }
        csvReader.close();
        return data;        


    }
```

When the method public void launchWCM1(IBLogonDataCSV data) passes or fails the Testng Report displays the object name which is not helpful in knowing what is the String value or the name of the URL failed in order to further debug .

Example:launchWCM1
Test class: com.seleniumtests.test.IBLogonCSV
Parameters: com.seleniumtests.dataobject.IBLogonDataCSV@de1b8a

What should be done to display the parameters in as a String Value ,something which will can be easily read like :
launchWCM1
Test class: com.seleniumtests.test.IBLogonCSV
Parameters: Name of the URL or something like that instead of the object name

Comment: Please try defining your custom com.seleniumtests.dataobject.IBLogonDataCSV.toString()

Comment: Thanks patrungel.Tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `toString()` and implement it to return readable meaningful vaule of your class.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
 String valueToReturn = "calculate from the properties";
 return valueToReturn;
}
```

Other way is, there are few third party extensions to TestNG are available, You can utilize available [data-provider-extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#data-provider-extension). For example, QAF has [in-built data providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) for XML/CSV/Excel/Json/DB.